# How to fix empty field then i edit a entity?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Post entity with a cover field that contains an entity - a picture

```
//src/Entity/Post.php
/**
     * @var Image
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cover_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $cover;
```

And when I edit Post using a simple function (Symfony auto created it, then i use CRUD to Post):

```
//src/Controller/PostController.php
  /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="post_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Post $post): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('post_index');
        }

        return $this->render('post/edit.html.twig', [
            'post' => $post,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

And form

```
    //src/Form/PostType.php
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('cover', ImageType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Cover'
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class
        ]);
    }
}

//src/Form/ImagetType.php

class ImageType extends FileType
{
    private $imagePath;
    /**
     * ImageType constructor.
     * @param $imagePath
     */
    public function __construct($imagePath)
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function(Image $image = null) {
                if ($image instanceof Image) {
                    return new File($this->imagePath . '/' . $image->getFile());
                }
            },
            function(UploadedFile $uploadedFile = null) {
                if ($uploadedFile instanceof UploadedFile) {
                    $image = new Image();
                    $image->setFile($uploadedFile);
                    return $image;
                }
            }
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'image';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'required' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

When a edit form is submitted, the cover field (even if it is filled with an object) comes up empty. How to make it so that when editing other fields of the Post entity, if there is something in the cover, so that it is saved?

P.S.
I use this example to download images - https://github.com/cirykpopeye/easy-image-uploading-with-symfony-4/tree/master/app

And i try to use this https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database 
but it did not help me with correct saving

Answer (score 0):

You should make little change in your save code.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($post); // Make persist (prepare you're entity to save in db
            $em->flush(); // Save prepared entity to database
            return $this->redirectToRoute('post_index');
}
```

Some useful links:

- [How to create entity from form](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/beginner-s-guide-to-symfony-3-forms/video/creating-new-doctrine-entities-using-symfony-s-form)
- [How works with ORM doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/getting-started.html)